# FacebookSDK - Unknown Type ACAccountCredentialRenewResult Error

Tags: iphone, ios6, ios4, facebook-ios-sdk, acaccount

I have installed newly updated `facebook SDK 3.5` in my mac. I took the tutorials given in facebook developer website and integrated the `facebook SDK` in my `XCode` Project.

[Facebook SDK Link](https://developers.facebook.com/ios/features/whats-new-ios-sdk-3.5/)

[Tutorial Link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/)

I just tried to run the facebook sample project. But I am getting the error as

```
Parse Issue: Unknown Type ACAccountCredentialRenewResult Error
```

and **project is not compiling**. I have seen that `ACAccountCredentialRenewResult` is available from `iOS 6` itself. But facebook says the SDK is compatible from **iOS 4.3+** . I am trying to run the project in **iOS 5.1 simulator and XCode 4.5**. Anyone help me to get rid of this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your Accounts framework optional and try.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a final solution but I put the missing enum at the top of my FBsession.h file.

```
typedef enum {
   ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRenewed,
   ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRejected,
   ACAccountCredentialRenewResultFailed
} ACAccountCredentialRenewResult;
```